# Framerate drops after few seconds in webGL projects

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl, frame-rate

I implemented a webGL solution to draw a lot of cubes.
I'm using big buffers to store the vertices, offsets, colors and drawing the cubes with a single call.
It works well with 60fps for the first 10 seconds.
After this the framerate drops to 30 fps and will not raise if I keep the tab active. If I switch to an other tab (without webGL stuff) for some time (about 1 minute I think) and return after this to my project, the framerate increases to 60 fps and drops after this again.
I think it is the GC, but if you see in the code, the drawScene function does nothing to produce data garbage, it is only calling the webGL draw function without producing new data...

I noticed this behaviour also with Three.js and Babylon.js. After some time the framerate drops and raises only if I left the tab with webGL inactive.

Some ideas how to fix it or clean the webGL states or other things?

I'm using the latest Chrome and Firefox.

```
        var program = utils.initShaders();
        utils.initAttributeLocation(program, 'position');
        utils.initAttributeLocation(program, 'offset');
        utils.initAttributeLocation(program, 'color');
        utils.initUniformLocation(program, 'viewMat');
        utils.initUniformLocation(program, 'projectionMat');

        var texture = utils.getTextureFromImage('resources/noodles.jpg');

        utils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

        var geometryDataOrg = getGeometryData(0, 0, 0); // 12 * 9 vertices
        var colorDataOrg = getColorData(); // 12 * 3 colors

        var geometryData = [];
        var colorData = [];
        var offsetData = [];

        for (var x=0; x<100; x++) {
            for (var z=0; z<100; z++) {
                var newOffsetData = getOffsetData(x, z, 0);
                for (var i=0, ilen=newOffsetData.length; i<ilen; i++) {
                    offsetData.push(newOffsetData[i]);
                }
                for (var i=0, ilen=geometryDataOrg.length; i<ilen; i++) {
                    geometryData.push(geometryDataOrg[i]);
                }
                for (var i=0, ilen=colorDataOrg.length; i<ilen; i++) {
                    colorData.push(colorDataOrg[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var buffer = utils.gl.createBuffer();
        utils.gl.bindBuffer(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        utils.gl.bufferData(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(geometryData), utils.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        utils.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(utils.attributes['position']);
        utils.gl.vertexAttribPointer(utils.attributes['position'], 3, utils.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        var buffer1 = utils.gl.createBuffer();
        utils.gl.bindBuffer(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
        utils.gl.bufferData(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(offsetData), utils.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        utils.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(utils.attributes['offset']);
        utils.gl.vertexAttribPointer(utils.attributes['offset'], 3, utils.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        var buffer2 = utils.gl.createBuffer();
        utils.gl.bindBuffer(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
        utils.gl.bufferData(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colorData), utils.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        utils.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(utils.attributes['color']);
        utils.gl.vertexAttribPointer(utils.attributes['color'], 1, utils.gl.FLOAT, false, 4, 0);

        utils.gl.bindBuffer(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

        var fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(60);
        var aspect = utils.getCanvasRatio();

        requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

        var projectionMatOrg = m4.identity();
        projectionMatOrg = m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, 1.0, 4096.0, projectionMatOrg);
        utils.assignUniformValue(utils.gl.FLOAT_MAT4, 'projectionMat', projectionMatOrg);

        var viewMat = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.123234262925839e-17, -1, 0, 0, 1, 6.123234262925839e-17, 0, 0, -20, -1.2246467996456087e-15, 1];
        utils.assignUniformValue(utils.gl.FLOAT_MAT4, 'viewMat', viewMat);

        utils.gl.bindBuffer(utils.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

        function drawScene(time) {
            utils.gl.clear(utils.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | utils.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            utils.gl.drawArrays(utils.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, colorData.length);

            requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
        }
```

Comment: maybe of interest: http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html

Comment: Are you by any chance using a laptop? If yo you might be experiencing performance throttling due to heat issues. My ultrabook shows the same behavior, its simply not made to run on 100% for longer than short periods of time.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm using a laptop... I will check this out if it is a "heat" problem.

Comment: Yes it sounds like a heating problem. To prevent overheating the graphics card will throttle the rendering. You can try using the card settings to reduce the quality of the rendering, this may give you the frame rate at the cost of rendering quality. Also make sure that all the cooling vents under and at the sides are clear for easy air flow. If the laptop is a bit old dust will get into the vents and block the radiators. You can use a straw to blow in the vents in reverse direction of airflow to dislodge dust (laptop off) then blow in the air flow direction. Dont get any spit in there.

Comment: And try not to contact the metal radiator parts they are very thin and can easily get damaged.

Comment: The laptop works well, but it is possible that a webGL program consumes that much power and it is getting slower after the time because of throttling. At the moment I can not check it with a desktop machine but I will keep that in mind. Thank you all for you responses.